# How do I find a link object with a specific id-tag using mechanize?

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, mechanize

I'm writing a web scraping script that at some point is supposed to click an anchor link with a specific id-tag. I can find the link by using BeautifulSoup, however I can't find a way to get the mechanize.Link object using mechanize.

This is my code so far.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("myUrl")

for link in br.links():
    if str(link.attrs["id"]) == "cell_14_2":
        click_link(link)
    break
```

I'm expecting to find the link object with id "cell_14_2" but I get an error message on the line:

```
if str(link.attrs["id"]) == "cell_14_2":
```

The message is:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What can I do to find the mechanize.Link object and click it?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes on the link object are held as a sequence of (name, value) pairs. So you should first create a dictionary before asking for an item by id. For example:

```
for link in br.links():
    attrs = dict(link.attrs)  # First create a dict
    if str(attrs["id"]) == "cell_14_2":  # Now you can ask for the `id`
```